# Where's the location of incognito Chrome cached files for Mavericks?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-mavericks, browser-cache, private-browsing

Just wondering the location of the cached files for incognito mode.. I know regularly it's in /users/{$user}/Library/caches/google...etc, but for incognito mode I have no idea where they are stored. I tried the /private/var/folders folders, but to no avail. Using chrome 36, osx mavericks. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's not caching to drive at all. After all, it's supposed to be incognito and file recovery is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

*(This should be a comment, but I don't have the rep yet.)*

You can run `sudo fs_usage -e -w -f filesys | grep 'Google Chrome' | grep '/'` to monitor Chrome's disk usage.

Comment: Instead of saying this should be a comment, just expand it a little to make it a more self-explanatory answer.